# Including an INI file inside a dll one

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ini

I would like to insert an external INI file inside a dll project, using Visual Studio. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @arne I am generating a dll file at the end to load it in my application.

Comment: Do you just want to copy an ini file to the same output dir as the dll? Why do you want it in the project?

Comment: @doctorlove I am having an ini file that I am copying to the dll file. But I don't want to drag it to the application to make it work. I want to include it to the dll file.

Comment: Bunch of thanks to the one who was putting -1. I don't know what's wrong with my question?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If you want to "embed" the ini file data inside the xml you'd have to hard code it, which defeats the purpose of an ini file

Comment: @doctorlove thanks for the clarification . and thus, I always have to include the INI file in the folder which includes the app and the dll file?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question isn't clear: it asks how to add a file t a project, then asks for the code. Which do you actually need? What are you stuck on? Adding a file to a solution is just a case of right-click + add existing file

Comment: Despite your re-wording, it's still unclear to me. Do you want (1) to use an external .ini file from within your DLL, (2) somehow *include* the entire .ini file *inside* the compiled DLL, or (3) add it to your *project* and do nothing else? (1) is trivial (open, read, parse), (2) makes -- as mentioned above -- no sense. (3) is trivial *and* useless.

Comment: @Jongware: You could add the INI file as a text resource, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a file of any type to your project, but this may not solve your problem. When the dll tries to read the file it probably won't find it.

You could just embed the data inside your dll's code, but this defeats the purpose of having an ini file. You will need to re-built the file if you ever want to change the configuration.

You can write a post-build step to always copy an ini file to the `$(OutDir)` folder then it will exist if you try to run this under a debugger, but ultimately you need to include the ini file with the dll when you release this.